# Populate Textboxes from a list using C# and winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

The following works to populate a `DataGridView`, however I do use it to populate `TextBox`es?
My commented out line threw an out of index error.

```cs
void PopulateProjectDetails()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnVal("db")))
    {
        var param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("@SearchText", Convert.ToInt32(selIDProject));

        List<Projects> projectlist = connection.Query<Projects>("dbo.spProjectsViewSearchByID", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<Projects>();
        txtProjectID.Text = selIDProject.ToString();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = projectlist;
        //txtProjectName.Text = projectlist[3].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the contents of `projectlist` in the debugger? With that error, that probably doesn't contain what you expect it to.

Comment: Only a novice here, but yes projectlist shows 1 record and shows the fields and data. It does work to populate the data grid view. There is two fields with "null" could this be the error?

Comment: If `projectlist` only contains one record, you'll obviously get an error on `projectlist[3]` because that's looking for the 4th element...

Comment: Oh... I thought that referred to column 4 of the returned record. Not the 3rd record that doesn't exist. So how do i retrieve all the column data from the one returned record and place into the existing text boxes on my form.

Comment: That depends. What is the `Projects` class? Does it have properties that correspond to those columns?

Comment: Projects Class is a model of the database table.

Comment: public class Projects
    {

        public int idProject { get; set; }
        public int EntityID { get; set; }
        public int SectorID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }

Comment: @primedbt you should edit those details into your post (the fact that there is only one item in your list, and it wouldn't hurt to add the code of your Projects class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running your stored procedure, `projectlist` only contains a single `Projects` object. When you are calling `projectlist[3]`, you're telling that list to use the **4th** element in that list. This is why you get the index exception. The `3` here is the zero-based index of which element you want. It's not in any way related to the columns in your database, or fields/properties of you `Projects` object.

If you want to access the first (and only) item in your list, you can simply do `projectlist[0]` (although that could still give you an error, if you stored procedure didn't even return a single item). If you wanted to verify this, one way to do that is to check `projectlist.Count`. See [List<T>.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netcore-3.1).

However that's still most likely not enough to do what you want. If you were to call `projectlist[3].ToString()` and you have not overridden the [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) method (which you probably didn't, and that's completely fine; it wouldn't be very useful in this specific case anyway) you would see something like "YourNamespace.Projects". It's just the default string representation of that class.

The good news is that if your code is populating the `Projects` object directly, then the values you want are already in the properties of the class. You should be able to do something like the following:

```
void PopulateProjectDetails()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnVal("db")))
    {
        var param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("@SearchText", Convert.ToInt32(selIDProject));

        List<Projects> projectlist = connection.Query<Projects>("dbo.spProjectsViewSearchByID", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<Projects>();
        txtProjectID.Text = selIDProject.ToString();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = projectlist;
        //Consider checking projectlist.Count before accessing projectlist[0]
        txtProjectName.Text = projectlist[0].ProjectName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do something like projectlist.First(), projectlist.FirstOrDefault(), or some other LINQ method. But that's probably a little more than is needed here.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. I will also add in the count line.